# Angular2: how to initially trigger Control.valueChanges

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

```
constructor(private _service: LocatorService) {
    this.counties = this.countyTerm.valueChanges
        .debounceTime(300)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .switchMap((term: string) => _service.getCounties(term));
}
counties: Observable<County[]>;
countyTerm = new Control();
```

As expected, `this.counties` is only populated once a value is entered into the `countyTerm` bound control.

How can I trigger `valueChanges` when this component is instantiated so that the set of counties is loaded initially?

I tried the following, but it had no effect (`implements OnInit` was added to the class):

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.countyTerm.updateValue('', { emitEvent: true });
}
```

Comment: You van give it a default value `countyTerm = new Control('Default value');`

Comment: That does give the control a default value, but it still doesn't trigger valueChanges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just start your stream out with a fixed value. Something like this:

```
this.counties = Rx.Observable.of('')
        .concat(this.countyTerm.valueChanges.debounceTime(300))
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .switchMap((term: string) => _service.getCounties(term));
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks! In my case I did have to omit "Rx." since I have Observable imported directly from rxjs/Observable".

Comment: You can now accomplish the same thing with rxjs's startsWith - this.counties.startsWith('').debounceTime(300).distinctUntilChanged().switchMap((term: string) => _service.getCounties(term))

Answer (score 3):

Use startWith RxJS operator to emit something before stream.

```
this.counties = this.countyTerm.valueChanges
    .startwith('')
    .debounceTime(300)
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .switchMap((term: string) => _service.getCounties(term));
```

http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/startwith.html

Answer (score 0):

With RxJS 6 / 7 new syntax:

```
this.counties$ = this.countyTerm.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      debounceTime(300),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap((term: string) => _service.getCounties(term))
);
```